# how to select empty fields inside mysql at specific condition?

Tags: mysql

I have this table in mysql

```
id |   chat_id   |   name  | grade | photo | phone
-------------------------------------------
1  |   1344564   |  mikel  |       |       |
```

so I want to select all empty fields(grade,photo,phone) in a single code line at specific condition

Comment: SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(MyField, ''))) = ''

Comment: I want this SELECT * FROM table WHERE chat_id="1344564" AND *=NULL OR *=""

Comment: What is this `IF *=NULL OR *= ''` and what do you get as a result by that?

Comment: @Mohammad reza Taheri Is it for whole table or selected row?

Comment: NULL and empty are conceptually different ideas.

Comment: I want to select empty fields with specific chat_id given

Comment: You **CANT** select fields based on a condition. You **CAN** select rows based on fields content.Is that what you want?

Comment: @revo `*=`  isnt a valid MySql syntaxis, in some data bases mean `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I want to select every empty fields in a selected row

Comment: @MohammadrezaTaheri Maybe English isnt your first language? but you cant get a dynamic list of field based on conditions. Or you want something else. Please show us what result you expect get from the query.

Comment: This sounds like an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)** to me.

Comment: u mean that I can't select empty fields at specific condition?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE chat_id="1344564" AND (`grade` IS NULL) OR (`photo` IS NULL) OR (`phone` IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

You can update grade, photo and phone in your query like below:

```
AND (grade = "" OR grade IS NULL)
```

Comment: but I want to select everything in a row is empty

Comment: forget about php, what you expect the query to return? Show us sample data and expected ouput from the query.

Comment: You can add like this in query for all fields that you want empty

Comment: I want query show me which fields in a specific row is empty

Comment: then you need to use foreach

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the query for when all of the other fields are empty? Like...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE chat_id="1344564" AND 
(grade = "" OR grade IS NULL) AND 
(photo = "" OR photo IS NULL) AND 
(phone = "" OR phone IS NULL)
```

Comment: select every empty fields where chat_id has specific value just in a single line

Comment: What do you want the output to be? What are you hoping to get from the query?